# What will be the correct sql to get the no. of student for individual group?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, multiple-tables

**meetings** which looks like this:

| meeting_ID | place |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

**study_groups** which looks like this:

| study_group_id | meeting_id (fk) | topic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Basics |
| 2 | 2 | Photography |
| 3 | 1 | Film |

**group_members** which looks like this:

| study_group_id (fk) | student_id (fk) |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 10 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 11 |

A `meeting` has many `study_groups` and each `study_groups` has many `students`.

I want to find number of student in each group individually for `meeting_id = 1`.

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT
    study_groups.study_group_id,
    study_groups.topic,
    study_groups.description,
    study_groups.group_member_limit,
    (SELECT COUNT(group_members.student_id)
     FROM group_members, study_groups
     WHERE study_groups.study_group_id = group_members.study_group_id
       AND study_groups.meeting_id = 1) AS no_of_students
FROM 
    study_groups
WHERE 
    study_groups.meeting_id = 1;
```

This is returning:

| study_group_id | no_of_student | topic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 but want `2` | Basics |
| 2 | 5 but want `3` | Photography |

Please correct my SQL kindly for the expected result.

**Additional**

Please also suggest me what should I should do if I want to see the `student` details(eg:name, email) in the same query, is it possible?

Where `student` table is

| student_id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz | xyz@exmpl.com |
| 2 | abc | abc@exmpl.com |

I want the result as:

| study_group_id | no_of_student | topic | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 but want `2` | Basics | xyz, abc (`demo`) |
| 2 | 5 but want `3` | Photography | abc, xyz (`demo`) |

Comment: why not grouping by group ID and counting the members

Comment: if i do this then it's saying `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right back with a subquery, but you want a *correlated subquery*.  This looks like:

```
SELECT sg.study_group_id, sg.topic, sg.description, sg.group_member_limit,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM group_members gm
        WHERE sg.study_group_id = gm.study_group_id 
       ) AS num_students
FROM study_groups sg
WHERE sg.meeting_id = 1;
```

The important part of the query is that `study_groups` is removed from the subquery so the subquery refers to the *outer* query.

I also introduced column aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: Thanks a ton Gordon Linoff, you changed my way of thinking. Will you please give me an idea about the *Additional* part?

Comment: @SumonSUtrodhar . . . That should be asked as a *new* question.  Your (original) question here has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the subquery. Just use a count distinct on group_members.student_id and add a group by statement that includes all the other columns in the main select query

Comment: I am very slow in sql, will you please give sql as answer?